# Errors not showing in ts-node

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, ts-node

When I have an Error in my code, compiling with ts-node, the error does not appear in the console.

For exemple:`let data = await fs.readFileSync(path);`

I have this code where I use "fs" to read a file, using a path that the function receive as parameter. But when the path is from a file that does not exists nothing happends in the console. The only thing that happens is that the requisition never finish loading.

If I put a console.log like this in the code, the error appears saying that the file does not exists : `console.log(fs.readFile(path, (data) => { }))`

It doesn't make sense, since the errors are supposed to show in the console. (This happens with lot of type of commum errors that make it harder to finish the application)

here's the repository with all the code https://github.com/Macintosh-1984/Pokedex_Express

somebody help please

Answer (score 0):

You are not capture the error on readFile

```
fs.readFile(path, 'utf8', function(err, data){
      // you have err here 
});
```

Comment: yeahh, to do it with readFileAsync I had to put in a try catch. Thank you!